# How can I generate a .xlsx time-tracking report with my .ics file exported from iCal?

Tags: excel, csv, reporting, icalendar, xlsx

Need to generate time tracking report (.xlsx or .csv) containing columns A-G:

```
 BEGIN_Date, BEGIN_Time, END_Date, END_Time, SUB_TOTAL hours, TOTAL_MH, TOTAL_HTD
```

Key: 
MH, monthly hours
HTD, hours to date

Using exported data from .ics file:

[EXAMPLE]

```
 BEGIN:VEVENT
 CREATED:20130527T032646Z
 UID:78AAAEC5-8DA5-4E33-8B50-74C95763C17D
 DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20131110
 TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
 SUMMARY:[EVENT_NAME_HERE]
 DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20131109
 DTSTAMP:20130527T032652Z
 SEQUENCE:2
 END:VEVENT
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste your code snippet into a new excel file in Cell A1; Cell A2 should contain 'CREATED:20130527T032646Z'

Cell A2 would contain 'CREATED:20130527T032646Z'

In cell B2 use the following formula to extract the date value:

```
=IFERROR(DATEVALUE(MID(MID(A2,SEARCH(":",A2,1)+1,8),5,2)&"-"&RIGHT(MID(A2,SEARCH(":",A2,1)+1,8),2)&"-"&LEFT(MID(A2,SEARCH(":",A2,1)+1,8),4)),"")
```

In cell C2 use the following formula to to extract the time value:

```
=IFERROR(TIMEVALUE(MID(MID(A2,(SEARCH("T",A2,SEARCH(":",A2,1)+1)),9),2,2)&":"&MID(MID(A2,(SEARCH("T",A2,SEARCH(":",A2,1)+1)),9),4,2)&":"&MID(MID(A2,(SEARCH("T",A2,SEARCH(":",A2,1)+1)),9),6,2)),"")
```

Remember to convert the Date and Time cells to Date and Time Format using 'Format Cells.'